# Libreoffice calc cell COMMENT displays wrong

Tags: libreoffice

Libreoffice calc (spreadsheet) **comments display *part-cropped*** when rollover mouse over cell,
so **full comment *not* visible when rollover**
but **displays correct in full whe click "show comment"** for individual cell or menu VIEW>Comments [to show all comments in sheet.
=on *Libreoffice 7.4.1.2* on Ubuntu 20.04..1 / Linux 5.4 desktop.

Weird thing is that no problem on another linux machine (Laptop) with *same* Libreoffice version.

I think it was fine on desktop as well as laptop, until maybe recently desktop problem started.

Any ideas???

I've compared settings on both machines, finding no obvious significant difference, (or changing differences especially if re OS appearance such as font resolution or even icons themes -without any luck).

I even installed earlier Libreoff version (alongside exisiting latest 7.4.1.2), but still same prob.

### *****Any ideas how to fix?**

**Update Sunday Oct1:**
+Works fine in SNAP Libreoffice-calc on desktop PC (tho don't want to use snap - cos slower +...) –
StephenOn3rdRock

Could it be because missing system file?
Tho I think I did try re-installing LO after purging (in muon) - tho I did not reboot inbetween I alos tried replacing desktop LO user profile folder with profile folder from OK laptop LO.

[image: image ...B2) =mouse-rollover comment display= displays cropped][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOdQ.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOdQ.jpg)

Comment: Works fine for me on v7.1.4.2 with ubuntu v 20.04.5 LTS. Does it display properly when you select `View > Comments`?

Comment: Read the *Images* section (it's the last one) of [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to see how you can add images in your post.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yay! I've cracked it: In my case at least:
**UNinstall libreoffice-qt5**